# How to capture the value of an element which is being returned by a data-bind attribute?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using ajax call and knockout data binding to get the values of an object from backend and showing in the UI. an element like this:

> ```
> <input id="bill" data-bind="value: billDate">
> ```

returns the date for a bill. In the UI I want to format the date so I have a piece of JS code like this:

> ```
> function formatDate(){
>     var billDate = $("#bill").val();
>     // the rest of the code
>     }
> ```

the problem is the JS code cannot capture the value of #bill element after the page is loaded to format it, however the element value already shows up in the UI. What should I do to solve this kind of problem?
I tried document.ready function but it did not work for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two approaches:

- make a [computed value](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html), `billDateString`, which formats `billDate()`. Use `data-bind="value: billDateString"`.
- make a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) with an `update` that converts the `valueAccessor()` into the string and sets it into the `element.value`, so you can do `data-bind="valueWithDate: billDate"`.

Comment: Note: with a `value` binding, the computed should be writable.